# Changing site-names in a bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I wan't to run a script that does some file alteration on `.php` files.
There are hundreds of `EmailController.php` files in different sites that should be modified based on the site-name depending on what folder they are located.

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/sitenames.txt
sed -i 's#'"/var/vmail/skeleton.com/"'#'"/var/vmail/$sitename/"'#g' /var/www/$sitename/web/EmailController.php
```

The easiest way would be to read `sitenames.txt` file that would contain the domain-names one per line and substitute that domain with `$sitename` in the bash script.

Comment: Thx. Pesa. Was just about re-format.

Comment: I would recommend moving this per-site configuration out of your code and into a config file.

Comment: Please clarify. Out of the php code or bash script code?

Comment: Out of the PHP code - a simple option would be to create a config in "ini" style and use [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php).

Answer (score 0):

@tom-fenech is right on in saying this should be in config file rather than hardcoded into your .php files.  Regardless, you need to change what you have. And, you'll need to do something like this to change to a config file anyways.

**Short Answer**

```
skeldir="/tmp/skeleton"
skelsite="skeleton.com"
sitename="example.com"

fgrep -lr --null "/var/vmail/${skelsite}/" "${skeldir}" \
| xargs -0 sed -i "" "s#/var/vmail/${skelsite}/#/var/vmail/${sitename}/#g"
```

Which is mostly equivalent to:

```
find "${skeldir}" -type f -print0 \
| xargs -0 sed -i "" "s#/var/vmail/${skelsite}/#/var/vmail/${sitename}/#g"
```

I like the `fgrep` version better because it runs `sed` on a smaller set of files than `find` (assuming your pattern isn't in every file).

**Long answer**

Putting this together:

```
$ cat /tmp/x.sh
#!/bin/sh

skeldir="/tmp/skeleton"
skelsite="skeleton.com"
sitename="example.com"

[ -d "${skeldir}" ] && rm -rf "${skeldir}"

mkdir -p "${skeldir}/subdir"

echo 'ignore this line' \
| tee "${skeldir}/file1.php" "${skeldir}/subdir/file2.php" "${skeldir}/file3.php" \
> "${skeldir}/subdir/file4.php"

echo "foo /var/vmail/${skelsite}/ bar" \
| tee -a "${skeldir}/file1.php" >> "${skeldir}/subdir/file2.php"

echo "BEFORE:"
echo "  Files that have \"${skelsite}\": $(fgrep -lr "/var/vmail/${skelsite}/" "${skeldir}" | wc -l)"
echo "  Files that have \"${sitename}\":  $(fgrep -lr "/var/vmail/${sitename}/" "${skeldir}" | wc -l)"

# make changes (--null/-0 ensures you can have spaces, etc, in filenames)
fgrep -lr --null "/var/vmail/${skelsite}/" "${skeldir}" \
| xargs -0 sed -i "" "s#/var/vmail/${skelsite}/#/var/vmail/${sitename}/#g"

# Alternate:
# find "${skeldir}" -type f -print0 \
# | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s#/var/vmail/${skelsite}/#/var/vmail/${sitename}/#g"

echo "AFTER:"
echo "  Files that have \"${skelsite}\": $(fgrep -lr "/var/vmail/${skelsite}/" "${skeldir}" | wc -l)"
echo "  Files that have \"${sitename}\":  $(fgrep -lr "/var/vmail/${sitename}/" "${skeldir}" | wc -l)"
```

And see what happens:

```
$ /tmp/x.sh
BEFORE:
  Files that have "skeleton.com":        2
  Files that have "example.com":         0
AFTER:
  Files that have "skeleton.com":        0
  Files that have "example.com":         2
```

You may consider running a backup before doing this! Something like:

```
$ rsync -avP --delete /var/www/$sitename/  /var/www.backup/$sitename/
```